# How to connect external JSON data with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, html, json, sorting

I need to do a table that sorts some data taken from a JSON file.

I found this and i need to make this work with an JSON file that is on the directory, when i try to link it just as file.json it shows an error

EDIT:
here is my current progress. Now I am trying to populate the tbody with the data from the JSON file.

http://konstantindichev.com/test/index.html

everything is in this index file

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>batter</th>
                <th>topping</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr spry:repeat="dsExample10">
                <td>{id}</td>
                <td>{type}</td>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{batters.batter.type}</td>
                <td>{topping.type}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myTable").tablesorter({
                sortList: [
                    [0, 0],
                    [1, 0]
                ]
            });
        });

        var opts = {
            debug: true,
                "theme": "blue",
                "widgetOptions": {
                "build_type": "json",
                    "build_source": {
                    "url": "http://output.jsbin.com/kuholujonu/1.js",
                        "dataType": "json"
                }
            }
        };

        console.log(opts);

        $('#myTable').tablesorter(opts);
    </script>
```

JSON FILE:

```
[
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,

    "batters": {
        "batter": [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
        ]
    },

    "topping": [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
},

{
    "id": "0002",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Raised",
    "ppu": 0.55,

    "batters": {
        "batter": [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
        ]
    },

    "topping": [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
},

{
    "id": "0003",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Old Fashioned",
    "ppu": 0.55,

    "batters": {
        "batter": [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
        ]
    },

    "topping": [
        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: could you, please, add all your code here?

Comment: http://konstantindichev.com/test/index.html here is mu current progress, i am trying to populate the tbody with the data from the json file